# Cannot stop a Service neither from an Activity nor a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-service

I have a Service that shows a Float Icon which shows the status of the application. But in some certain times I want to hide the float icon by stopping the Service. So I have a Broadcast to handle that, but the problem is I cannot stop the service by calling `context.stopService(new Intent(context, FloaticonService.class))`.

**Here is the BroadcastReceiver `FloaticonReceiver.java`**

```
public class FloaticonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, FloaticonService.class));
    }
}
```

**And here is the Service code `FloaticonService.java`**

```
public class FloaticonService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView floatIcon;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        floatIcon = new ImageView(this);
        floatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(floatIcon, params);

    }

}
```

Comment: is `BroadcastReceiver` triggered?

Comment: @Sunny Yes, I tested that, by displaying a `Toast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add this on your `FloaticonService` class:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    windowManager.removeView(floatIcon);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helped to hide the `floatIcon`. But will that kill the Service too or it will continue running after that? (How can I make sure?)

Comment: It will kill the service because `onDestroy()` will only called if the Service class is killed.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this and its working:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Intent mOnBootServiceIntent = new Intent(context, OnBootService.class);

        context.startService(OnBootServiceIntent);
     //or                        
        context.stopService(OnBootServiceIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "is active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```